# Rank over multiple columns executed by the server?

Tags: sql, paging

How can I implement the RANK() function taking into account two columns for the ranking? The main column does not have unique values. This is the query:

```
select *, RANK() over (order by score, posteddate desc) as rank from Post
```

I need to implement pagination without the offset limit pattern and I thought a kind of ranking function would be ok. I have a partial implementation which only works with uniques, using the '>' or '<' operands on the key used for pagination.

Any idea? I cannot find a solution online.

Cheers.

Edit upon request: I am using c#.

Answer (score 0):

We do paging with `.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)` and `.Take(pageSize)`. You just need to make sure you have ordered the data first. This will all execute on the server.

For example, if you want the content for page 4 and each page should contain 20 results:

```
var pageIndex = 4;
var pageSize = 20;
var pageContent = db.Post
    .OrderBy(p => p.score)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.posteddate)
    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize);
```

The generated SQL here automatically includes the addition of `ROW_NUMBER()` and `TOP`. It works pretty well up to a couple hundred thousand records.

Comment: But that would not execute on the server.

Comment: @Villason: I've updated my answer now that I understand it more.

Comment: @CORY, the question is about not using LIMIT OFFSET, which is the translation of your answer.

Comment: @Villason: What's the reasoning behind not being able to use that technique?

Comment: @CORY, 1st: a business requirement is that the url is not "hackeable" in a way a user can randomly access a page (like typing &page=2000). 2nd: offset has a performance penalty for scanning all the items up to the page.

Comment: `RANK()` would be equivalent in performance to `ROW_NUMBER()` which is what `Skip/Take` generates in the SQL, so the performance argument is moot. What are you planning on using instead of page numbers? If you're using a unique key as the "last value" from which to continue paging, that's just just as "hackable". You would need a system that uses a secret key to generate a hash or something as the "next page number" -- send that back to the server, use the key to reverse back to the page number, but that's all presentation layer. You can still use the Skip/Take on the backend.

Comment: Agreed on the performance point. I disagree on the second point about a secret key. Too complicated and I am not using sequential ids.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but I found a better approach as described in http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( SELECT *
           FROM sales
          WHERE sale_date <= ?
            AND NOT (sale_date = ? AND sale_id >= ?)
          ORDER BY sale_date DESC, sale_id DESC
       )
 WHERE rownum <= 10
```